# Stylus middleware in Express not working?

Tags: express, stylus

In `app.coffee` I have

```
stylus = require("stylus")

...
app.use stylus.middleware
    debug: true
    src: __dirname + "/stylus"
    dest: __dirname + "/public/css"
    compile: (src) -> 
        console.log(stylus(src))
        return stylus(src)
```

I included the styles in `layout.jade` like:

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/styles.css")
```

But in Chrome network tab, I see canceled for styles.css why is that?

When I point the browser directly to `/css/styles.css`, I get

> `Cannot GET /css/styles.css`

Whats wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have the `static` middleware properly configured and working and positioned AFTER the stylus middleware in your middleware stack? The stylus middleware is just going to read the `.styl` file and write the corresponding `.css` file but it expects the `static` middleware to then find the `.css` file and serve it.

Also note that your `src` and `dest` file hierarchies should correspond directly. By that I mean even counting all intermediate directories if you list the recursive contents of one directory (`ls -R` or similar) then the ONLY difference should be `src` contains `.styl` files and `dest` contains exactly corresponding `.css` files. Don't tack a `/css` prefix onto one but not the other, for example.

Comment: The static middleware is defined like: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))`. Full `app.coffee`: http://pastie.org/5595573

Comment: Remove the `app.router` line. You almost never need to manually change the location of the `app.router` middleware, and doing so almost always causes problems such as this.

Comment: I tried removing the `app.router` line but it still results in 404 ... btw, that line was in the default app.js as generated by express CLI. I tried looking in the docs, but can't find what `app.router` actually does too.

Comment: Oh, I found whats the problem ... it seems `dest` cannot be a nested folder (eg. `__dirname + "/public/css"`)? Changing it to `__dirname + "/public"` fixes it. Any ideas why its like that, I'm sure its not so rigid?

Comment: The src and dest hierarchies just need to correspond correctly.

Comment: @PeterLyons You should edit your answer and add this comment, I spent AGES trying to get this to work and having the same nesting (`/stylus/css` and `/public/css`) fixed it!

Comment: @PeterLyons This seems very odd to me. If I pass in `{src: __dirname + "/stylus", dest: __dirname + "/public/css"}`, I would expect `/stylus/style.css` to map to `/public/css/style.css`. Instead the accepted solution is to pass in `{src: __dirname + "/stylus", dest: __dirname + "/public"}` and then `mkdir stylus/stylesheets; mv stylus/*.styl stylus/stylesheets`. I understand why the fix works, but why didn't the original work? Where did `style/style.css` map to? The hierarchies in `src` and `dest` *do* correspond exactly - they both have style files only, there are no directories in either.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I run into the same issue and as long as @PeterLyons answer is correct I found that adding the **extra slash** after `css` directory name also seems to fix the problem.

(without coffee)

```
var stylus = require('stylus');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(stylus.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/stylus',
        dest: __dirname + '/public/css/' // <-- additional slash after "css"
    }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Not sure if this is stylus version-related issue and wasn't/was present before but still it's quite confusing to me.

Comment: This fixed it for me, though I had to do that with the 'src' key-value since I did not change the dest.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me crazy for a few hours so I thought I'd share :)

I serve my external files from /public

So my stylesheets are in /public/styles. All I had to do was put my .styl files in a folder called /styles in the root of my project.

```
modules.app.use(modules.stylus.middleware({
    debug: true,
    src: __dirname + '/',
    dest: __dirname + '/public/',
    compile: compile
}));
```

I got around the whacky path requirements as I'm always going to ask for styles in /styles

**GET /styles/website.css** serves **/styles/website.styl** from the **root /** directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

//stylus
function compile(str, path) {
return stylus(str)
.set('filename', path)
}

app.use(stylus.middleware(
{ src:'/public/css'
 , compile: compile
}
));
```

put your file.styl in public.css it will be compiled there too!
the problem must be the src directory, it seems you are pointed to modules/stylus, anywhere I am not an exprert but this way works